# unable to get database values

Tags: php, html

Hello I am working on a multiple choice quiz script but I am unable to retrieve the values of option. I am calling the options using form method using radio button but I am only able to see the radio button not the database option script.

```
echo '<input type="radio" value="', $ row ['opt1'],'"</>';
```

Opt1 is the string stored in database but it is not fetching in form using with radio button

Comment: can you post your html and php code

Comment: echo '<input type="radio" value="', $ row ['opt1'],'"</>';

Comment: add name attribute in input tag

Answer (score 1):

change it like this

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'.$row['opt1'].'"/>';
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to give name to radio button other wise you can not get the value of selected radio button.